# Как в PHP set_error_handler перехватить все ошибки PDO?

Tags: php, исключения, pdo, обработка-ошибок

Работаю с базой данных MYSQL через интерфейс PDO.
Нужно ошибки баз данных записывать в отдельный log.
Есть ли у возможность стандартными методами в set_error_handler определить, что это ошибка PDO и получить объект PDO, чтобы потом из него извлечь всю нужную информацию?
Или нужно парсить errstring на наличие "PDOException и т.д." и получать доступ к объекту PDO своими силами?
P.S. errcontext - не рекомендуется использовать, т.к. устарел.

Comment: лучше сделайте хэндлер на исключения, переведите pdo в режим выбрасывания исключений. Ну а дальше всё просто, всё что PDOException - ваше.

Comment: Я сейчас так и делаю: PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, неудобно, что приходится каждый раз парсить $errstring на наличие PDOException и хранить объект PDO доступным снаружи класса, где он используется, чтобы получать к нему доступ, когда произойдет ошибка. Может быть есть стандартный функции для выделения ошибок БД из общего числа или общепринятые библиотеки? Или для php это приемлемо, что я в обработке ошибок использую свой хандлеры, с который следующий разработчик будет знакомится? Благодарю спасибо!

Comment: `каждый раз парсить $errstring на наличие PDOException`. знакомы с конструкцией `try ... catch \PDOException ... catch \Exception`? `хранить объект PDO доступным снаружи класса, где он используется, чтобы получать к нему доступ, когда произойдет ошибка` - не понял ход вашей мысли. Вообще, можно сделать свой отнаследованный от PDOException класс, где определить все что нужно.

Comment: try catch уже из области динозавров, по-моему? давно пользуюсь единым обработчиком на всё приложение. Да, уже это и сделал PDOExceptionExtend в котором прописал нужные мне методы.